# Removing duplicate labels from different tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am making a map using data stored in `PostGIS`. I am serving multiple layers in the map (POIs, Cartographic, Roads etc.) and when I label these layers I have repeating labels, this is because some features are represented as both Polygons and Points in my data (present in both the cartographic layer and the POI layer).

I tried to fix the issue of duplicate features by running a Join in `PostGIS` based on the names and then removing the features from one table, using this query:

```
select c.name AS cartographic, subtype AS carto_type, type_strin AS pois_type, p.name AS pois 
from cartographic c , isl_pois_priority p
where (lower(c.name) LIKE lower(p.name)) AND c.a1 > 0
```

At first I though this would work but then I realized that the names in both the tables are not exact matches, they are mostly the same but there are some differences, as shown here:
[image]

The point layer contains spaces( ) while the polygon layer has hyphens (-).

How can I account for differences such as this when I look for duplicate features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) module of PostgreSQL. It provides several functions to determine similarities and distance between strings.

I think something similar to this will work for you.

```
select c.name AS cartographic, subtype AS carto_type, type_strin AS pois_type, p.name AS pois 
from cartographic c , isl_pois_priority p
where (metaphone(c.name, 20) LIKE metaphone(p.name, 20)) AND c.a1 > 0
```